# SQL ignore case in group by? (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Can you ignore case in a group by? For example if there is a table of states but it has records with "Alabama" and "alabama", or "Alaska" and "alaska" and you want the group by that column but just get back a single 'group' for Alabama and Alaska.

thanks

Comment: Sounds like your database is not [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) properly.

Answer (score 31):

Just use UPPER:

```
select upper(state), count(1)
  from your_table
 group by upper(state);
```

Comment: or LOWER or INITCAP, if you prefer one of those :)